# How do I report profits from selling stocks on 1040NR?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, income

I sold stocks in 2021 and made a profit. However, my brokerage did not report this to IRS as my account is identified as nontaxable. Therefore they didn't withhold any tax and they did not issue any tax forms. How can I report this on my 1040NR? This is income not effectively connected to US business or trade.

Thank you

Mary

Comment: Are you certain that these sales are taxable in the US? Depending on your country of residence and your physical presence in the US during the year, capital gains may not be taxable at all in the US and therefore would not need to be reported.

Comment: I am a nonresident alien with a J1 visa. I am exempt from counting days for the substantial presence test. However I should still be taxed at 30% rate for gains and dividends. I am sure about the dividends since I received a 1042s. I am not sure about gains from selling stocks. I did not receive any forms for these.

Comment: Gains are typically 'sourced' to your country of residence [vs dividends which are typically sourced to country of dividend country origin], pending some tie-break type contexts depending on the other country and its tax treaty with the US. Highly recommend you research this issue specifically.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: but US has complicated residence rules. For _most_ income, aliens are taxed as resident if LPR or meeting the substantial presence test in 7701(b), which F,J,M,Q students&scholars don't for a certain number of years, but capital gains (other than real property, which is always US-taxed) use a different, simpler 183-day presence test. OP: **see "Sales or Exchanges of Capital Assts" in [pub 519 Tax Guide for Aliens](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2021_publink1000222353)** (answer: sch NEC). Skimming _all_ of p519 is a good idea for an alien in US.

Comment: I have read p519 and it says stock trading is NEC if it is the only business activity. However, my fellowship grant (which is my only other source of income) is considered business activity. Does that mean my stocks are effectively connected income?